# Ruby determine image dimension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

Excuse, How i can determine the image dimension?

Example If i have a image of "800x600>"

How i can know "800x600>" dimension?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are working with paperclip and have an image path.

```
geo = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(path_to_image)
geo.width # 800
geo.height # 600
```